# How do I use my email alias as original sender with GSUITE & Nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, nodemailer, google-workspace

I have a form with two fields, username and email address, so users can leave their names for a reservation list for a new product coming soon.

I have properly set `nodemailer` with gsuite and also an `alias` email attached to the admin user of the gsuite account.

What I would like to know is how can I have the email alias actually appearing on the field `sent` on the email.

As we can see below, the email header message is correct, also if the user tries to reply, it will be to `no-reply@....`.

The thing is that you can notice that the user primary account offial user email, namely `deboradeoliveira@....` is still there, showing up, which can lead to the users getting that email and sending emails...

Is there any way to use the email alias as the sender, or GSUIT will always show the official user primary email on this field, forcing me to pay/create a new user on the admin console just to do what I intend?

[image]

Below is my mailer handler:

in this case, `YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` is this `no-reply@...` alias email of `deboradeoliveira@....`

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS = process.env.MAILER_MY_EMAIL;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",  
      user: YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      serviceClient: process.env.MAILER_CLIENT_ID,
      privateKey: process.env.MAILER_PRIVATE_KEY
  }});

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { name, recipientMail } = req.body

    const mailerRes = await mailer({  name, recipientMail })
    res.send(mailerRes)
}

const mailer = ({  name,  recipientMail }) => {
    const message = {
        from: YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        to: `${recipientMail}`,
        subject: `New message from ${YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS}`,
        replyTo: YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        html: `<b>Hey there ${name}! </b><br> This is our first message sent with Nodemailer`
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) =>
            error ? reject(error) : resolve(info)
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to get Gmail to use the email alias?

Comment: Did you work this out? Would be really helpful to have an answer on this.

Comment: @JCutting8 I had to use a dedicated email address for this. As far as I could see there is no solution for this. I guess that Google will enforce this so we pay more to use the service. There could be some intermediate service / different service than google, that could be better

Comment: @Arp I actually worked this out, but have no idea how because this was from some time ago. I'm successfully sending emails using NodeMailer using a GSuite account that has an alias, and its not showing the original email to the user. I can't see anything different to what was posted here, except that in the input for `from` I use the format `No-Reply <noreply@example.com>` rather than just the email. If that's not it, then may be to do with how the service client and private key is created.

Comment: @JCutting8 Oh great! It might be a feature on GSuite, or a bug resolution!